# How to include multiple select statements in one table

Tags: mysql, sql, database

```
Select count(Gender)  as 'FOScout' from stormtroopers_officer join st_officer_assign on stormtroopers_officer.STID=st_officer_assign.STID where Gender='Female';
SELECT count(Gender)  as 'FNScout' from stormtroopers_nco join st_nco_assign on stormtroopers_nco.STID=st_nco_assign.STID where Gender='Female';
SELECT count(Gender)  as 'FTScout' from stormtroopers_troop join st_troop_assign on stormtroopers_troop.STID=st_troop_assign.STID where Gender='Female';
Select count(Gender)  as 'MOScout' from stormtroopers_officer join st_officer_assign on stormtroopers_officer.STID=st_officer_assign.STID where Gender='male';
SELECT count(Gender)  as 'MNScout' from stormtroopers_nco join st_nco_assign on stormtroopers_nco.STID=st_nco_assign.STID where Gender='male';
SELECT count(Gender)  as 'MTScout' from stormtroopers_troop join st_troop_assign on stormtroopers_troop.STID=st_troop_assign.STID where Gender='male';
SELECT count(Gender)  as 'Total Female Scouts' from stormtroopers_troop WHERE Gender = 'Female';
SELECT count(Gender)  as 'Total Male Scouts' from stormtroopers_troop WHERE Gender='Male';
SELECT count(Gender)  as 'Total Male Scouts' from stormtroopers_troop;
```

When I execute this obviously it will come in separate tables, while what I want is to put them in one table as shown in this pic

[image]

Comment: Croas join them all as subqueries

Comment: @shawnt00 Could you explain more please ?

Comment: You should combine a few of these and use CASE. Then do as Deepak says

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your query to:

```
SELECT
(Select count(Gender)  as 'FOScout' from stormtroopers_officer join st_officer_assign on stormtroopers_officer.STID=st_officer_assign.STID where Gender='Female') as 'FOScout',
(SELECT count(Gender)  as 'FNScout' from stormtroopers_nco join st_nco_assign on stormtroopers_nco.STID=st_nco_assign.STID where Gender='Female') as 'FNScout',
(SELECT count(Gender)  as 'FTScout' from stormtroopers_troop join st_troop_assign on stormtroopers_troop.STID=st_troop_assign.STID where Gender='Female') as 'FTScout',
(Select count(Gender)  as 'MOScout' from stormtroopers_officer join st_officer_assign on stormtroopers_officer.STID=st_officer_assign.STID where Gender='male') as 'MOScout',
(SELECT count(Gender)  as 'MNScout' from stormtroopers_nco join st_nco_assign on stormtroopers_nco.STID=st_nco_assign.STID where Gender='male') as 'MNScout',
(SELECT count(Gender)  as 'MTScout' from stormtroopers_troop join st_troop_assign on stormtroopers_troop.STID=st_troop_assign.STID where Gender='male') as 'MTScout',
(SELECT count(Gender)  as 'Total Female Scouts' from stormtroopers_troop WHERE Gender = 'Female') as 'Total Female Scouts',
(SELECT count(Gender)  as 'Total Male Scouts' from stormtroopers_troop WHERE Gender='Male') as 'Total Male Scouts',
(SELECT count(Gender)  as 'Total Male Scouts' from stormtroopers_troop) as 'Total Male Scouts'
```

Comment: Hope it helps. Please mark it as an answer once it works well for you.

Comment: Great! Easy and unexpected! that works actually well

Comment: just fix this small problem in the fourth line. "as 'MOScout'),"

Comment: Done. Thank you.