# How to combine select statements, each in a different column

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Here is the statements that I am working on.
It is to create a single query that displays the number of male or female scouts by rank category (Officer, NCO, or Troop) and the total female and male scouts.

```
SELECT
(Select count(Gender)
from stormtroopers_officer
join st_officer_assign on stormtroopers_officer.STID=st_officer_assign.STID
where Gender='Female' AND st_officer_assign.Role = 'Scout') as 'FOScout',

(SELECT count(Gender)
from stormtroopers_nco
join st_nco_assign on stormtroopers_nco.STID=st_nco_assign.STID
where Gender='Female' AND st_nco_assign.Role = 'Scout') as 'FNScout',

(SELECT count(Gender)
from stormtroopers_troop
join st_troop_assign on stormtroopers_troop.STID=st_troop_assign.STID
where Gender='Female' AND st_troop_assign.Role = 'Scout') as 'FTScout',

(Select count(Gender)
from stormtroopers_officer
join st_officer_assign on stormtroopers_officer.STID=st_officer_assign.STID
where Gender='male' AND st_officer_assign.Role = 'Scout') as 'MOScout',

(SELECT count(Gender)
from stormtroopers_nco
join st_nco_assign on stormtroopers_nco.STID=st_nco_assign.STID
where Gender='male' AND st_nco_assign.Role = 'Scout') as 'MNScout',

(SELECT count(Gender)
from stormtroopers_troop
join st_troop_assign on stormtroopers_troop.STID=st_troop_assign.STID
where Gender='male' AND st_troop_assign.Role = 'Scout') as 'MTScout',

(SELECT count(Gender)
from stormtroopers_officer
WHERE Gender = 'Female') as 'Total Female Scouts',

(SELECT count(Gender)
from stormtroopers_troop
WHERE Gender='Male') as 'Total Male Scouts',

(SELECT count(Gender)
from stormtroopers_troop) as 'Total Male Scouts';
```

These are the statements that I want to combine, because it looks too long and I believe that there is a way to do it in an easier way

This is the output how it looks like and I dont want to change it to multiple rows or different number of columns.
[output is here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sIPcl.png)

Comment: Did none of the answers solve your problem? If not, please edit the question so that an answer can be found. If one did, please mark it accepted so that other users can find it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this will do what you want:

```
select FOScouts, FNScouts, FTScouts, MOScouts, MNScouts, MTScouts,
FOScouts+FNScouts+FTScouts as `Total Female Scouts`,
MOScouts+MNScouts+MTScouts as `Total Male Scouts`,
FOScouts+FNScouts+FTScouts+MOScouts+MNScouts+MTScouts as `Total Scouts`
from (select count(case when gender='Female' then 1 end) as FOScouts,
      count(case when gender='Male' then 1 end) as MOScouts
      from stormtroopers_officer st_o
      join st_officer_assign st_o_a 
      on st_o_a.stid = st_o.stid
      where st_o_a.role = 'Scout') o
     join
     (select count(case when gender='Female' then 1 end) as FNScouts,
      count(case when gender='Male' then 1 end) as MNScouts
      from stormtroopers_nco st_n
      join st_nco_assign st_n_a 
      on st_n_a.stid = st_n.stid
      where st_n_a.role = 'Scout') n
     join
     (select count(case when gender='Female' then 1 end) as FTScouts,
      count(case when gender='Male' then 1 end) as MTScouts
      from stormtroopers_troop st_t
      join st_troop_assign st_t_a on st_t_a.stid = st_t.stid
      where st_t_a.role = 'Scout') t
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `GROUP BY`, if you can live with the results as separate rows:

```
Select Gender, a.role, count(Gender)
from stormtroopers_officer o join
     st_officer_assign a
     on o.STID = a.STID
group by Gender, a.Role;
```

Comment: Thanks but it's not what I'm looking for, the role should be 'SCOUT'

Answer (score 0):

You can declare variable and assign each count to variable.
    Finally select all the variables assigned.

```
   DECLARE @Countofficer INT;
   DECLARE @Countnco INT;
   SET @Countofficer =(Select count(Gender)
                       from stormtroopers_officer
                       join st_officer_assign on 
                       stormtroopers_officer.STID=st_officer_assign.STID
                       where Gender='Female' AND st_officer_assign.Role = 'Scout')

    SET @Countnco =(SELECT count(Gender)
                    from stormtroopers_nco
                    join st_nco_assign on 
                    stormtroopers_nco.STID=st_nco_assign.STID
                    where Gender='Female' AND st_nco_assign.Role = 'Scout')


    SELECT @Countofficer AS stormtroopers_officer ,@Countnco AS stormtroopers_nco
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your query to:

```
SELECT
(Select count(Gender)  as 'FOScout' from stormtroopers_officer join st_officer_assign on stormtroopers_officer.STID=st_officer_assign.STID where Gender='Female') as 'FOScout',
(SELECT count(Gender)  as 'FNScout' from stormtroopers_nco join st_nco_assign on stormtroopers_nco.STID=st_nco_assign.STID where Gender='Female') as 'FNScout',
(SELECT count(Gender)  as 'FTScout' from stormtroopers_troop join st_troop_assign on stormtroopers_troop.STID=st_troop_assign.STID where Gender='Female') as 'FTScout',
(Select count(Gender)  as 'MOScout' from stormtroopers_officer join st_officer_assign on stormtroopers_officer.STID=st_officer_assign.STID where Gender='male') as 'MOScout',
(SELECT count(Gender)  as 'MNScout' from stormtroopers_nco join st_nco_assign on stormtroopers_nco.STID=st_nco_assign.STID where Gender='male') as 'MNScout',
(SELECT count(Gender)  as 'MTScout' from stormtroopers_troop join st_troop_assign on stormtroopers_troop.STID=st_troop_assign.STID where Gender='male') as 'MTScout',
(SELECT count(Gender)  as 'Total Female Scouts' from stormtroopers_troop WHERE Gender = 'Female') as 'Total Female Scouts',
(SELECT count(Gender)  as 'Total Male Scouts' from stormtroopers_troop WHERE Gender='Male') as 'Total Male Scouts',
(SELECT count(Gender)  as 'Total Male Scouts' from stormtroopers_troop) as 'Total Male Scouts'
```

I answered this on the below post:
[How to include multiple select statements in one table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49958409/how-to-include-multiple-select-statements-in-one-table/49958589?noredirect=1#comment86933659_49958589)

Please mark it as a answer, if it did so.